# R + converting a integer to a hh:mm format using regex + gsub

Tags: regex, r

interval is a subset of 5 minute intervals for a 25 hour period

```
> interval
 [1]   45   50   55  100  105  110  115  120  125  130  135 2035 2040 2045 2050 2055 2100 2105 2110 2115 2120 2125
```

I want to insert `:` to put it in a time fomat that i can convert to a time format

```
> gsub('^([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2})$', '\\1:\\2', interval)
 [1] "45"    "50"    "55"    "1:00"  "1:05"  "1:10"  "1:15"  "1:20"  "1:25"  "1:30"  "1:35"  "20:35" "20:40" "20:45"
[15] "20:50" "20:55" "21:00" "21:05" "21:10" "21:15" "21:20" "21:25"
```

I have got it working for nearly all my examples. 
How do I get it so that it works on the numbers `"5"` ... `"45"    "50"    "55"`

Found this duplicate here but this does not use [gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272457/convert-an-integer-column-to-time-hhmm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to make sure all the inputs have at least 4 characters:

```
gsub('^([0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{2})$', '\\1:\\2', sprintf('%04d',interval))
# "00:45" "00:50" "00:55" "01:00" "01:05" "01:10" "01:15" "01:20" "01:25"
# "01:30" "01:35" "20:35" "20:40" "20:45" "20:50" "20:55" "21:00" "21:05"
# "21:10" "21:15" "21:20" "21:25"
```

Comment: thought it might be easy :) could you briefly explain the `%04d` for my clarity and reference. tks

Comment: or a variation: `sub("(..)", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d", interval))`

Comment: Try running `sprintf('%04d',interval)` so you get an idea of what it does. You can look at `?sprintf` to get some examples of how the function works, and how different formats are specified. As you can see, it pads zeroes on the left of the number till there are four digits (in this case). `sprintf` is a very old function coming from the C language, with an arcane syntax. I use it because I know how to do basic things quickly, not because it is easy to learn.

Comment: tks, i did run `sprintf('%04d',interval)` I was more on about the `%` and the `d` but I guess it is jsut syntax then.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub`:

```
> sub('..\\K', ':', sprintf('%04d',interval), perl=T)
#  [1] "00:45" "00:50" "00:55" "01:00" "01:05" "01:10" "01:15" "01:20" "01:25"
# [10] "01:30" "01:35" "20:35" "20:40" "20:45" "20:50" "20:55" "21:00" "21:05"
# [19] "21:10" "21:15" "21:20" "21:25"
```