# ggplot:print hourly format in x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data frame

```
df

Time Load1 Load2

0 375.5 375.5

10 374.6 374.6

20 350.1 350.1

30 334.5 334.5

40 304.9 347.7

50 285.4 331.6
```

....       ....  ..   ...

I am unable to change the format of the Time column from 10,20 to be like this: 00:10, 00:20...

I want to draw this data frame using    ggplot by this command:

```
    P<- ggplot(df,aes(Time))+

    geom_line(aes (y=0))+

   geom_vline(xintercept = 0,)+  

    geom_line(aes(y=Load2,linetype = "twodash"))+ 

    geom_line(aes(y=Load1, linetype = "solid"))+

    theme(legend.position='none')+ # to remove the legend.

    geom_vline(xintercept = 650, colour="purple",linetype ="longdash")+

    geom_vline(xintercept = 1500, colour="purple",linetype ="longdash")+

    geom_vline(xintercept = 2200, colour="purple",linetype ="longdash")+

    labs(title = "Daily load demands", x = "Time of day", y = "Power 
consumption_Kw/h")

    P
```

however, the currently result is :

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DchPM.jpg)

I tried following command to change the time format :

```
 df<- data.frame(Time,Load1,Load2)

 df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%H:%M:%S")
   P<- ggplot(df,aes(df$Time))+...
```

But there is no change. please, is there any suggestion to draw the x-axis in the format 05:00, 10:00, 15:00, 20:00 instead of 500, 1000,1500,2000. many thanks.

Comment: Just to understand. If in your dataframe you have `10` that would be `10:00`? Because I don't see in your data Frame something like 10,20... EDIT: Oh ok I got it now. `10` would Need to ba just 10 minutes right?

Comment: Duplicate: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272457/convert-an-integer-column-to-time-hhmm

Comment: Thanks fasttouch for your answer. first sorry for unclear question. Yes, 10 need to be just 10 minutes in this format "00:10", however 1000 need to be 10 am in this format "10:00". and I want to show that in the figure. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @fasttouch for the Duplicate: check answer link and I  change the format by  this code :
     temp2 <- mapply(function(x, y) paste0(rep(x, y), collapse = ""), 0, 4 - nchar(Time))
  temp <- paste0(temp2, Time)
# Time <- temp

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can be your solution. If is only a problem of visualisation (and not of data) why don't you simply change the Labels in ggplot? You can use something similar to (Note: the code I am giving you here is simply an example that DON'T APPLY to your case)

```
scale_x_continuous( breaks = c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016, 2017), 
      labels = c ("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
```

That would change labels on the x-axis from years to letters.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell the format of your Time entry beyond 60 minutes, but here is a possible solution. Other manipulation may be needed depending on the minute format of your data.

Convert the minutes to appropriate format, first left-pad with 0's (uses stringr package):

```
df$Time <- stringr::str_pad(df$Time, 4, "left", pad = "0" )
```

or the `sprintf()` from the link above is a simple, elegant solution that does the same: `df$Time <- sprintf("%04d", df$Time)` One might work better depending on your original Time format.

then convert this to a POSIXct format time:

```
df$Time <- strptime(df$Time, format = "%H%M")
```

Then format the time appropriately in ggplot. Using your existing plot, just add:

```
P + scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

Comment: Many thanks @Matt L. , by adding your codes, your answer solve most of the problem. However, Three things I need to mange it of the new figure. These are today's date (month and day number) is appeared with X-axis label.
second, 00:00 of the next day. Third, the vertical lines are disappeared I need to return them, as the below link for the new figure image: 

https://liveplymouthac-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yaseen_yaseen_plymouth_ac_uk/Documents/current/code%20for%20the%20expermant_/code%20for%20the%20expermant_/afte%20T.R/Rplot01.jpeg

  
many thanks