# How to convert 09:35:36 from integer to time format?

Tags: r

I have the following data. order.time is integer format. How to I convert it into time format, without adding date?

```
order.time
9:58:58
9:58:26
9:56:28
9:56:18
9:56:12
```

I have tried using `parse_date_time`, `strptime`, but all the functions add date and time zone in the final data. I only want to convert time from integer format to a format where I can draw plots with time in the x-axis

Comment: can u provide more information pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an integer column to time HH:MM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272457/convert-an-integer-column-to-time-hhmm)

Comment: Base R has a date/time object but no time only object.  You will need to use a package like chron, or format the date/time object to only show the time portion on the axis.

Answer (score 2):

In the tidyverse, the `hms` package provides an S3 class for time of day:

```r
> time <- hms::as_hms(c("9:58:58", "9:58:26", "9:56:28", "9:56:18", "9:56:12"))
> time
09:58:58
09:58:26
09:56:28
09:56:18
09:56:12
> class(time)
[1] "hms"      "difftime"
> str(time)
 'hms' num [1:5] 09:58:58 09:58:26 09:56:28 09:56:18 ...
 - attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
```

The function `as_hms()` also takes integer arguments, but only in seconds:

```r
> (time_in_hours <- c(6, 9, 12))
[1]  6  9 12
> hms::as_hms(time_in_hours * 3600)
06:00:00
09:00:00
12:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.POSIXct()`:

```
times <- as.POSIXct(c('9:58:58', 9:58:26), format = '%H:%M:%S')
```

Then you will have a time object, i.e: `times[2] - times[1]` will give you: Time diff of -32 secs.

You can plot these as is, also they can be formatted by using `format(x, format)`.

Ex: `format(times[1], format = '%H:%M:%S')` will give you '09:58:58'.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the `anytime` package. It works almost all of the time.

```
library(anytime)

order.time <- anytime(order.time)
```