# In R how do I covert a column with minutes as an integer to a time format?

Tags: r, time, format

I have a column of numbers in a csv file that represent minutes. How do I convert these into a time format in R?

Comment: `lubridate::minutes(your_column_goes_here)` or `as.difftime(your_column_goes_here, units = 'mins')`

Comment: I'm new to R, thanks for the really quick answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an integer column to time HH:MM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272457/convert-an-integer-column-to-time-hhmm)